# How to pass data/props to a dynamic route in Next.js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js, next.js13

I have a homepage in Next.js that fetches all of my month data from a database. I also have a dynamic month page that *should* render a month page with the individual month data from the database. The problem is I can't seem to figure out how to pass this month data to the individual month page.

On the homepage I render a list of links for each individual month. How do I pass the individual month data to each individual month page?

```js
export default async function HomePage() {
  const months = await getAllMonths();

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Months</h1>
      <ul>
        {months.map((month) => (
          <li>
            <Link
              href={`/month/${month.year}-${month.month}`}
            >{`${month.month} - ${month.year}`}</Link>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The only solution I've seen is context which doesn't seem to apply since I'm not rendering a component that I can wrap and the other solution is to pass it via the URL which I don't want to do as this data could contain sensitive information.

Versions I'm using:

- next: 13.5.3
- react: 18.2.0

Answer (score 2):

Next doesn't support what I was trying to do or anything like it so here's how I solved it instead.

Inside of the individual month page:

```
const params = useParams();
const slug = params.slug.toLowerCase();

useEffect(() => {
    const getData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${url}/month`);
        const allMonths = response.data;
        monthsByIdObject = allMonths.reduce(
          (prev, curr) => ({
            ...prev,
            [curr.id]: curr,
          }),
          {}
        );

      
        currentMonth = monthsByIdObject[slug] || initialMonthState;

        // use currentMonth data

      } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
          throw error;
      }
  };

    getData();
  }, []);
```

Hopefully this helps someone else! As Xiduzo mentioned above, I could probably refactor this to just retrieve the data for a single month to simplify things further.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the parameters from your dynamic routes as described [in the documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes)

in your case this will be something like `/month/[yearMonth].tsx`

Where you can get the parameters like:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
 
export default function Page() {
  const router = useRouter()
  return <p>year-month: {router.query.yearMonth}</p>
}
```

Comment: Thanks for responding! Perhaps I need to update my question with more details. The data I'm trying to receive in each individual page is data from a database that I hit when I call getAllMonths. That data contains way more than the year/month that is available via the routing in Next.js

Comment: in the route `/month/[yearMonth].tsx` you could then call another endpoint to fetch data for a specific month. Something like `const data = getMonthData(router.query.yearhMonth);`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the App router, you can simply get the router props like params as Page component props, sth like this:

```
 export default function Page({ params: {month} }) {
  return <div>My Post: {month}</div>
}
```

or you can use useRouter hook that imports from `next/navigation`

Here is the full documentation:
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/routing/dynamic-routes